# Ruby: comparing two Arrays of Hashes and mapping one to the other

Tags: ruby

Can you help me to optimize my code for the following problem:

An array of hashes named expected_tasks has tasks. Each task has a user that has to execute an action and contains fields. 
The expected_tasks are related to the actual_tasks. 
We want to execute the expected_task[action] on the actual_task["id]". 
Therefor want to be able to select the actual_task["id"] where all the fields have the same value.

In the end this means that the expected_tasks[0] matches to the actual_tasks[0] because their fields are exactly the same. When their is a match, we can use actual_task["id"].

This is what the data looks like:

```
#the fields_to_check is an extraction of the keys of the expected_tasks minus user and action
fields_to_check = [ 'field_to_check_1', 'field_to_check_2' ] 

expected_tasks = [{ 'user' => 'user', 
                     'action' => 'action_y', 
                     'field_to_check_1' => 'value_a', 
                     'field_to_check_2' => 'value_a' },{
                     'user' => 'user', 
                     'action' => 'action_x', 
                     'field_to_check_1' => 'value_b', 
                     'field_to_check_2' => 'value_b'} ]

sparse_actual_subtasks = [{ 'id' => '1' , 
                     'field_to_check_1' => 'value_b', 
                     'field_to_check_2' => 'value_b' },{
                     'id' => '2' , 
                     'field_to_check_1' => 'value_a', 
                     'field_to_check_2' => 'value_a' }]
```

The piece of code to map the id from actual_task to the right action + user from the expected_task:

```
expected_tasks.each do |expected_task|

  mapped_tasks = []

  actual_task = sparse_actual_subtasks.find do |actual_task|
    fields_to_check.all? do |field| 
    expected_task[field] == actual_task[field] 
    end
  end

  #map action and user to task with id 
  actual_task['action'] = expected_task['action']
  actual_task['user'] = expected_task['user']
  mapped_tasks << actual_task

  puts mapped_tasks

end
```

Comment: I could not understand your explanation above :'(

Comment: I am going to try and rewrite :D @BKSpurgeon

Comment: In this rewrite please paste data structure examples that people can paste on their code.

Comment: @tokland I have fixed the json structure and tested the code. It is working as expected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def mapped_tasks(expected, subtasks, fields)
  fields_match = ->(t1, t2) {fields.all? {|f| t1[f] == t2[f]}}
  expected.map do |e| 
    subtask = subtasks.find {|s| fields_match.(e,s)}
    subtask ? e.merge(subtask) : nil
  end.compact
end
```

should do the same as your original.

- use `merge` rather than explicitly adding each field you want
- create a lambda to name the condition of "all relevant fields matching".  this makes the loop within which it is called more readable.
- rather than procedurally declaring an array and adding items to it, simply use map to chang *all* the expected items.  the ones that don't match are changed to nil, and we remove them at the end using `compact`

notes on the original code:

- the data structures that we're assuming exist seem ill-fitted to the problem.  if they're within your control, consider simplifying them.  this should make the solution to the problem here more natural
- avoid extraneous information in your variable names.  it gives the illusion of greater clarity but in fact makes the code harder to read at a glance.  eg `fields` is a clearer name than `fields_to_check`